# Python 2 vs 3: Lambda Operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Has there been a change in the way lambda functions work between Python 2 and 3? I ran the code in python 2 and it works fine, but fails in Python 3 which I am trying to port my code into in order take advantage of a 3rd party module.

```
pos_io_tagged = map(lambda ((word, pos_tag), io_tag):
    (word, pos_tag, io_tag), zip(zip(words, pos_tags), io_tags))
```

I have researched multiple questions on Stackoverflow and read a couple of articles such as [this](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) but still can't find the answer. Is there any resources that I can view?

Comment: The return value of `map()` has changed.

Comment: And the way you can use argument assignment has also changed; unpacking is no longer supported.

Comment: Check out http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#tuple_params for info on passing tuples to `lambda` functions.

Comment: I'm going to go the assumption you got a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`  on the `lambda` signature here. In future, **always** include the full error message!

Comment: `lambda wpio: wpio[0] + (wpio[1],)` would do the same thing without tuple argument unpacking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using parentheses `()` with your lambda expression, which will confuse it. Try the following:

```
pos_io_tagged = map(lambda word, pos_tag, io_tag:
    (word, pos_tag, io_tag), zip(zip(words, pos_tags), io_tags))
```

Look [here](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_lambda.php) for more information.